# Bug in scipy PPoly.root

Tags: python, scipy, polynomials

Here is a MWE

```
import scipy
p = scipy.interpolate.PPoly(x=[1.426618795448907, 3.6900413078920606], 
                            c=[[-0.0003473223894645246],
                               [0.031172356603618657],
                               [0.14183014380119674],
                               [-0.4766926173965321]])
p(p.x), p.roots(extrapolate=False)
```

The result is:

```
(array([-4.76692617e-01,  6.07153217e-18]), array([], dtype=float64))
```

So at `x[0]`, y is negative, at `x[1]`, y is positive (just barely) so **a root must exist** within the interval, but `roots` can't find it.
If I set `extrapolate=True`, three roots are found, including the correct one.

Is this a bug, or am I making some error here?

Comment: According to the documentation, there should be `m+1` values of `x` and `c` should be `(k,m)`, where `k` is the degree. Why is `c.shape = (4,1)` and `len(x) = 2`? Those are inconsistent shapes.

Comment: @jared m=1, k=4, so x.shape=(2,) and c.shape=(4,1). These are not inconsistent shapes. If they were there would be an error message when I try to compute `p(p.x)`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that evaluating `p(x[1])` seems to give a positive value, that value is at machine precision and can't be trusted to be positive. When you do `p.roots(extrapolate=True)`, you'll see that the root it gives is 3.69004131, which is just barely larger than `x[1]`, showing that `x[1]` isn't sufficient.

Comment: While I understand that this is a machine precision issue, the various parts of an object should work together. If the eval of a polynomial gives different signs at two ends of an interval, then a root should be inside the interval.